# Downloading Problem

Tags: list, library, download, threshold

we have requirement where we are downloading huge data in GB's. i have created powershell script which works very fine for Normal download of document library whose list threshold values not exceeded.

I just want to know, if it will create any problem in downloading if its list threshold value exceeded? i know it will throw error. but after increasing list threshold, it will cause any problem? any suggestions?

Comment: I think you should be more concerned about uploading the files to document library.

Answer (score 2):

In general you should't be storing documents of big size in SharePoint. A better approach would be to store it on a file share or FTP and simply link to the file from SharePoint.

You technically cannot store a file larger than 2 GB (2047 MB) to SharePoint. This is the maximum size. If you want to allow files up to 2 GB you'll need to increase the connection time-out in IIS and increase the maximum upload size for the web application.

1.SharePoint limit's the upload to 2GB due to IIS's worker process w3wp.exe, to upload a file you need to use all the IIS available memory to upload the full stream.  Each w3wp.exe worker process runs well with 2-4GB of memory, this is not a boundary just a good idea (on x64), therefore this makes sense to me that the SP2010 team have limited any file upload to 2GB. If you start to download the file , your site would be very slow because all the IIS process is used for downlaoding the large documents.

2.Also be aware that increasing you upload file size to 2 GB has performance ramifications so it a user uploads a file and there is no memory available no new requests can be handled until the memory is available again.

I am sure there will be performance sure with huge GB of data.

Comment: I am not worried about uploading here. I am more concerned about downloading. also I don't have files larger than 50MB.its all word documents,pdf,email messages etc which makes total size bigger.